# R Performing operation on huge number of files faster way

Tags: r

I have to run this operation on 10200 text files:

```
s[s$POS==sample[tail(which(sample$obs_pval == min(sample$obs_pval)), 1),1],])
```

and write in one file output of every operation on every file which looks like this:

```
        ID            CHROM      POS
20_49715203_T_C_b37    20      49715203
```

So I will end up having one file with 10200 lines like above.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
fileNames <- lapply(Sys.glob("ENSG*.txt"), read.table)
s=read.table("snpPos", header=TRUE)

for (fileName in fileNames) {

  # read original data:
  sample <- read.table(fileName,
  header = TRUE,
   sep = ",")

  # create new data based on contents of original file:
  allEQTLs <- data.frame(
    File = fileName,
    EQTLs = s[s$POS==sample[tail(which(sample$obs_pval == min(sample$obs_pval)), 1),1],])

  # write new data to separate file:
  write.table(allEQTLs, 
    "EQTLs.txt",
    append = TRUE,
    sep = ",",
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Right now I am doing it in standard way, and it takes a lot of time. Is there is a better/more efficient way to write this code?
I should also mention that every of these ENSG*.txt files has at least 4000 lines. The largest file has 15 million lines.

Comment: The readr package can improve performance when reading/writing text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fread and fwrite from the data.table package if it's the read/write operations taking up most of the time. (You can check that latter condition with Rprofiling tools-- eg. the Rprof function.)